# ASP.Net onclick not firing when checkbox is checked

Tags: asp.net

I'm building an asp.net/C# application that has several true/false questions, along with some multiple choice questions, in it. I've written code for this, and for some reason the onclick() event is not triggering when a checkbox is clicked. This is confirmed working in another app ; I don't understand why it isn't working here. Please see the relevant code below. I've sat this code side-by-side with the known working code, and can't find any anomalies. Does anyone have an idea why this isn't working?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ChkQuestion1(obj) {
        var chk1a = document.getElementById("<%=chkFalse1.ClientID %>");
        var chk1b = document.getElementById("<%=chkTrue1.ClientID %>");

        if (obj.checked == true) {
            chk1a.checked = false;
            chk1b.checked = false;

            obj.checked = true;
        }
    }

    function ClientValidation1(source, arguments) {
        var chka = document.getElementById("<%=chkFalse1.ClientID%>");
        var chkb = document.getElementById("<%=chkTrue1.ClientID%>");
        if (chka.checked == false && chkb.checked == false) {
            arguments.IsValid = false;
    }
}
</script>

<tr>
    <td valign="top">1.</td>
        <td width="70px" valign="top">
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkTrue1" runat="server" Text=" " onclick="ChkQuestion1(this)" />
            <asp:Label ID="lblTrue1" runat="server" Text="True"></asp:Label></td>
        <td width="90px" valign="top">
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkFalse1" runat="server" Text=" " onclick="ChkQuestion1(this)" />
            <asp:Label ID="lblFalse1" runat="server" Text="False"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="lblP1" runat="server" Text="This is a test True/False Question."></asp:Label>
            <asp:CustomValidator ID="cvTwo" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please select correct answer true/false." ToolTip="Please select correct answer true/false." ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="Employee" ClientValidationFunction="ClientValidation1">*</asp:CustomValidator>
        </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I have imported your code into a new application on my development machine and it runs as expected. I can onyl assume you have a typo somewhere, or you have defined the same method more than once in the same project by the same name and it is calling the second declaration of this method instead of the one you want it to (Search for ChkQuestion1 in the project just to make sure it has not been repeated someone in a copy and paste error.

Comment: How do you know that it's not triggering the event? How are you verifying that assumption?

Comment: If I change the onclick event to read onclick="return confirm('This is a test.')", then it operates as expected and generates a confirmation box when I check the box - however, if I try to execute the function in the code, it ignores it.

Comment: An addendum to the above - I know it isn't executing ChkQuestion1(this) because I removed all code from the function and replaced it with a return confirm('This is a test'); statement - if I check the box, the window does not pop up.

Comment: do you have a asp:scriptmanager?